# Do i need Node.js in Python like I would with PHP?

Tags: php, python, twisted, node.js, nonblocking

I have been using PHP for some time now. And I have been thinking about learning Node.js to go along with it to use the non blocking idea for creating an online game or app. There is quite a bit of info on using the two together. Using Node as part of the back end of a game could really speed up some aspects of the game, especially if the game allows users to play against each other in real time.

Well, lately I have also been looking into learning Python (yes I have a lot of time on my hands). There are many features about it over PHP which I really like. But for the use of Node.js to do the background work like I was considering with PHP, I cannot find much information at all. I have also noticed that Python does have some threading features. As I am still very new to Python's world, would I even need Node.js in Python? Can Python handle these kind of features that Node.js can? Or would there still be benefits to using Node, or would I actually *need* it.

As a side note, since I started looking up Python, I also discovered Twisted which seems to be another framework like Node. But Twisted is written in Python. So in either of the cases above would Twisted be better (aside from the fact that Twisted seems to have been out longer and is more stable than Node). I just mean in general is it worth using at all, either Node or Twisted? And if so is one better than the other with Python?

Sorry for the big question, but I'm just so unsure and n00b in this area. Thanks.

---

So as it stands, after reading the helpful answers, I see the following options:

1. PHP + JS
2. Python + Twisted
3. Python + PyJamas
4. Python + Node.js
5. Node.js
6. Twisted

---

1. I already know PHP and am comfortable with it, and am currently learning JS. This this was a major possible route for me. But I was also leaning away from PHP to Python because the in general features of the language I liked.
2. This option I thought might be more plausible than #3, using Twisted to handle the networking port to allow the player to play live with each other.
3. This just makes it so you don't have to learn JS, which to me doesn't seem like that big of a deal. I've already started studying it and it's not that hard to learn. But like was mentioned in a question, mixing things like ; and {} could potentially have some issues.
4. Like #2, but with Node.js. Mostly I see the addition of Node to handle the networking aspect to let the players be able to play in a live/real-time game. And the majority of the code would be in Python.
5. Sole Node.js was a consideration as well as it is the single language route. But it doesn't have the same benefits of learning and using Python either (it being a general scripting language I can use in, and out of web design. A big reason I wanted to learn and use it.).
6. Ans as #5 but I was not considering an only Twisted route until reading the comments. While it seems plausible, it doesn't really involve one of the two languages I want to learn, Python and Node.

The above seems to be the main routes I can go. Now I'm still not really sure which route to go. I really want to learn both Node and Python. So it seems I may just need to learn the two separately. But I still need to pick a choice for this project. And so far I am liking numbers 2 and 5, with 6 a close to 5 since Node and Twisted have some very similar functionality. And 1 as a mention because that's what I already know. But I was wanting to learn something new anyways. So still, really numbers 2 and 5. Or 4 as it's similar to 2. Hah, I still need to do some homework. Maybe it deserves another question.

EDIT (9-19-2012): I just wanted to update, to say that I am using mostly Node.js currently for development. And plan on using Redis for PubSub functionality to give the appearance of real time page updates, as I do not need true real time as in games, or in paired content editing.

Comment: Your point 6 is incorrect: Twisted *is* Python.  The whole point of Twisted is exposing as much event-driven networking stuff as plain Python APIs.

Comment: Oh ok. I see. I knew it was written python, but i guess my view of it was slightly skewed.

Comment: It's worth noting that Python is a language, Twisted extends Python to the web and Node.js extends Javascript to the web. Just like you can't use Ruby on Rails with PHP (unless you want to put in a lot of stitchwork to combine two components that were never meant to be), you can't use Twisted with Node.js, and you can't use Node.js with Python.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While Python can definitely be used for Asynchronous Programming, it doesn't feel natural, even with Twisted, if you compare it to Node.js it just doesn't look or feel *that* nice.

Since you're planing on doing a real-time Web Game, you'll most likely will end up using [WebSockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262543/using-html-5-websockets).

WebSockets are based on HTTP and use the upgrade header to initiate the bi-directional connection, that means, that you can easily have both your normal Server *and* your WebSockets run on port 80, if you need a lot of fall backs to support older Browsers, then there's always the almighty [Socket.IO](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO-node).

Depending on how complicated your front-end will be I'd rather go with [express.js](http://expressjs.com/) or just write my own stuff.

Having both the front-end and the game in the same process has (obviously) a lot of advantages, you can fetch a lot of information without the need of having to query the database.

Another big "feature" is, that you don't have to context switch between the client logic, and the server's logic. That might seems like a small benefit at first, but besides the fact that you won't type `;` in Python and don't forget your `{}` in JS after having worked continuously on either side for a couple of hours, you will also be able to re-use code between Server and Client. Again that might look like a small benefit at first, but good multi player games always run a lot of stuff on the client, just to compensate the lag, also Python and JavaScript are quite different in place so having to re-write portions of JS in Python takes time and may even introduce bugs.

*(Now on to the shameless plugs...)*

I've done 2 multi player games with Node.js already, although the have no HTTP front end both games run quite a lot of JS on the Client:
[Multiplayer Asteroids/Geometry Wars Crossover](https://github.com/BonsaiDen/NodeGame-Shooter)
[RTS Concept (a bit like Eufloria)](https://github.com/BonsaiDen/NodeGame-Orbit)

Also, while JSON seems to fit perfectly for sending the data between Browser and client, you'll soon find out that it uses **a ton** of bandwidth, since I encountered the same problem I've written some specialized library which saves up to `45%` traffic:
[BiSON.js](https://github.com/BonsaiDen/BiSON.js)

Again, having JavaScript both on the Server *and* the Client lets one re-use code and therefore save development time.

So to sum it all up I would strongly suggest to go with Node.js:

1. Re-usable code, less context switching therefore shorter development time
2. V8 is *faster* than Python in many cases.
3. No concurrency issues, everything is async by default.
4. Node.js is the next big thing, jump on the bandwagon now.
5. It's JavaScript! ;)

Comment: Yea the same language on both ends is appealing. But using two doesnt really feel all that far fetched to me, as its the same idea as using JS with PHP. Not long ago i looked into two of the node.js frameworks,express and geddy. But I have not done a lot of homework on either. And if I use node, I would like to use a framework as I know how beneficial they can be.

Comment: Also, in regards to BiSON, this reminds me of mongodb, which uses a binary JSON. Which I would like to use for development. So im not sure how that would fit into the mix with BiSON. Again like mentioned before, I still have some homework to do.

Comment: @luckysmack There are a couple of different "binary" JSON alikes out there, I don't know exactly what Mongo uses, but I suppose they use one that's not focused on being small in size, but rather fast for reading. The normal JSON is not the best thing to have in regards of read speed, so doing a binary one and packing in additional information will give a huge speed increase.

Comment: "While Python can definitely be used for Asynchronous Programming, it doesn't feel natural, even with Twisted, if you compare it to Node.js it just doesn't look or feel that nice" Why do you think so?

Comment: Since I asked this, python now has async/await and does much better in this regard. Currently, I do use some node but primarily focus on python.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's so much that it's better because it's Python-on-Python, but because you can do both the game part *and* the web part in Twisted.

**EDIT:**

Also, [Pyjamas](http://pyjs.org/).

Comment: Yea thats the same draw of node.js, is that I can code the whole thing in the one primary language rather than separate the server and client side. I also want to learn python for some of its other features that php does not have. Its much better as a general scripting language, which is why it is one of the possible routes I wanted to take.

Answer (score 2):

If you like callback-oriented programming, twisted and nodejs are the thing for you. Otherwise, you could take a look at [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/). It is similar to twisted/nodejs in that it is an asynchronous framework, but it allows you to write code just like you would do in a threaded approach.

It achieves this by doing coroutines-based magic behind the scenes.

Comment: gevent and Twisted are not comparable like this.  Twisted is a highly featureful network programming library, in addition to a library for writing event-driven programs.  gevent has few network programming features and only a bare stub of an event-driven programming system.  It's basically **just** a wrapper around co-routines (and if you like co-routines, you can find similar things that are actually integrated into Twisted nicely).

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of using Node.js is its strengths which is well documented at http://nodejs.org/#about. While you can certainly use a server-side language and a frontend stack for your needs,  I think writing all code in 1 language will be a huge productivity boost.

if i were you, I'll attempt to write most of my code in 1 language as much as possible. So I do not think you should try to use Node.js together with Python (Twisted or Tornado) . It seems to have some kind of overlap.

Just imagine the coolness of writing all of your code in JavaScript. ;)

Comment: When did javascript become a cool language? Personally, I hate it, especially the 'everything is a string/float' typing. And the inheritance mechanism. And the slightly different handling in every browser. Frameworks help a lot, but still the language remains rotten :) If only possible I would write Python both server and client side.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you're talking about having a system in place to do some kind of processing in the background that you want to do asynchronously. If that's the case you might consider using some kind of queueing system.  This way you can put a message into the queue until it gets processed by a pool of worker processes.

[Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) makes this pretty easy to do, but getting RabbitMQ (or another message broker) configured correctly might be a bit of a pain if you haven't done that before.